# The app might not install if the strings or images declared in your app’s manifest are incorrect

Tags: nuget, xaf, desktop-bridge

I building an XAF Winforms App [located here](https://github.com/kgreed/SBD.GeneralLedger) following [this blog](https://blog.delegate.at/2019/03/31/how-to-precache-an-xaf-winforms-application.html)

I am having a difficult time getting my Desktop Bridge application to pass the
Windows App Certification Kit tests

The report states that the App Resources tests fail.

```
Error Found: The app resources validation test detected the following errors:
The test was blocked from execution. Please try re-running the validation. If the test execution remains blocked then please contact support.
Impact if not fixed: The app might not install if the strings or images declared in your app’s manifest are incorrect. If the app does install with these errors, your app’s logo or other images used by your app might not display correctly.
How to fix: Fix the problem indicated by the error message. See the link below for more information:
App Package Resource Validation
```

The report also has errors in the Package Sanity Test

```
Blocked executables
Error Found: The blocked executables test has detected the following errors:File SBD.GL.Win10\DevExpress.XtraReports.v18.2.Extensions.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
```

I have tried re-generating the image files and looking through Package.appxmanifest

The help [that the error message links to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests#app-manifest-resources-test)  does not contain the error text to look up.

[Update]

I think the issue is related to Nuget installing packages that 
I am asking about this [at Dev Express](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T735306/xaf-nuget-packages-for-projects-to-go-in-the-windows-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the DevExpress forum, this looks like a false positive from WACK tests. I would recommend to proceed with the submission.

Comment: The first time I tried, I got an error. However it does upload now.